# trying to understand DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to get a better understanding of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

1) For persisting data, the class only has a `SaveChanges` method. Does that mean changes only to a specific record cannot happen?

2) If the data in the database is changed (by another application), how does the context get up-to-date information? Is this handled automatically, or is the data late binding? I don't see any kind of `Refresh` method.

Any useful references on this is also appreciated.

Comment: you seem to think the dbContext is holding everything in memory.  When you perform a query, it's querying the database - i.e. it'll be getting the updated information

Comment: @Jonesy Ok, I see that the "records" returned are IQueryable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean changes only to a specific record cannot happen?

Yes, this is true AFAIK. But you can create multiple `DbContext` instances without any problem.

> If the data in the database is changed (by another application), how does the context get up-to-date information?

The data is not loaded when the context is constructed but when it is requested:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var items = db.MyItems.Where(i => i.Something == true);
    var list = items.ToList(); // <= here the DB is queried
}
```

`items` will be a `IQueryable<MyItem>` object and as long as you keep it a `IQueryable` the DB is not actually queried. Meaning you can add additional `Where` or `OrderBy` without DB-access. As soon as you convert it to `IEnumerable` (e.g. with the `ToList` from my example) or execute some specific methods (like e.g. `First`) the DB will be queried.

Answer (score 1):

1) `SaveChanges` saves all unsaved changes, that are 'visible' by current DbContext (changes to entities loaded from this dbcontext, new entities added to `DbSet`s of this dbContext, entities 'attached' to this context via `dbContext.Entry(someObject).State = ...`).

If you want save only one entity - you must not change other entities, or have different dbContext, or play with `State`. Last two are "strange", so just change you code so it doesn't touch entities you don't want to save. For example, do not add new objects via `Add` (hold then in separate variables). Also, there is a `AsNoTracking` method in DbSet that `detaches` loaded objects once they read and you can freely change them - DbContext will not track this entities and will not "see" this changes.

2) There is a `Reload` method for already loaded entity: `dbContext.Entry(someObject).Reload()`